# After upgrading to Gradle 5.4.1 and Android Stuidio 3.5 RC 3, crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease task is gone

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

Before the upgrade, calling `assembleRelease` would then call `crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease` which would upload deobfuscation files. But now `crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease` task is gone, as a result strack traces in Firebase's Crashlytics are not deobfuscated.

Anyone came across this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured it out: downgrade gradle plugin to 3.4.2

No one bothered to mention in release notes that 3.5 version comes with this surprise, but the pop-up to update gradle plugin works flawlessly.

Hope this will help others.

Comment: or maybe you have to upgrade the fabric gradle plugin
see : https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#july-10-2019

Comment: Once i upgraded to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2 things started being deobfuscated again. But yeah wasnt very happy with having a release go out with firebase not deobfuscating things

Comment: @abdelalieramli thanks for your input. I'm still using the downgraded gradle plugin with fabric version 1.25.4 so maybe upgrading the fabric can solve the issue. Did you encounter the same problem?

Comment: yes @zeke I had the same issue. Now I am using `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'`

Answer (score -1):

There is no need anymore to manually upload mapping file.

1. To preserve the info Crashlytics needs for readable crash reports, add the following lines to your config file:

   -keepattributes *Annotation*
   -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
   -keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
2. To let Crashlytics automatically upload the ProGuard or DexGuard mapping file, remove this line from the config file (app/proguard-rules.pro):

   -printmapping mapping.txt

Taken from [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android)

Comment: I know all that ... Title says "After upgrading..."